# Dell XPS stuck at Preparing to enter BIOS setup

Tags: boot, bios, dell-xps

I recently expanded my C drive backwards with the EaseUS partition master and after a reboot, it is now stuck at just the dell logo or a 25% full progress bar when entering the Boot Menu or BIOS Setup. What can I do to fix this?

Pictures:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Laptop Model: Dell XPS 13 9310

Comment: Can you reverse your steps?  If not you may have to reinstall Windows

Comment: Do a cmos reset, power down and unplug the PC, remove the battery (laptop) and cmos battery for 15 minutes, reinstall batteries and see if it will post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BIOS corruption is not connected to any disk operation.

You can't do a
[BIOS Reset](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000124377/how-to-perform-a-bios-or-cmos-reset-and-clear-the-nvram-on-dell-systems),
because you can't enter the BIOS.
In short, you are completely blocked with a bricked computer,
and you truly need to force-install the BIOS.

I don't know what went wrong, but it's more likely to be a
power surge/cut, rather than partition resize on the disk.

Force-install requires some tools that you probably do not posses,
so my advice is to bring the computer to a repair-shop, that will be
able to find the right BIOS version and the know-how on installing
it to a bricked computer.

If the computer is recent enough to still be on warranty, call
Dell Support first.
Even if the warranty has elapsed, they might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with the 8910 that I am on right now. I dual boot Fedora Workstation (35 at the time) & Windows 10. I went to fedora and ran a disk management tool that showed I had corrupted files on my windows partition. So for me, I downloaded the [windows installation media tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-installation-media-for-windows-99a58364-8c02-206f-aa6f-40c3b507420d) and reinstalled windows, then repaired my hard-drive on my Linux distro to fetch any lost data I wanted to retrieve.

To be honest what I just explained is a pretty common fix for this situation from what I understand, although I know it isn't ideal. 2BH I have never ever once had any screen get stuck when booting to Linux, which is why I boot to Linux now, and keep a copy of windows solely to be able to use my Font-lab 8 License.

If you do want to try and fix the issue without reinstalling you will either need to have a partioning/disk-managment tool that you can use in bios (which would have likely prevented this problem in the first place) or you will need a second machine with an extra m.2 slot on the motherboard. If either of those options are viable, you may be able to prevent a reinstall.